# How to set the maximum disk size of a database MySQL, Oracle, PostGreSQL or DB2?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, db2

This is how I do in SQL Server:

```
Create Database MyDatabase
on (Name='MyDatabase_Data',
    Filename='c:\db\BdUnisanta_Data.mdf',
    Size= 20MB,
    FileGrowth = 10%,
    Maxsize=100MB)
log on 
    (Name = 'MyDatabase_log',
     Filename = 'c:\db\MyDatabase_Log.ldf',
     Size = 5MB,
     FileGrowth = 5%,
     MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
     )
```

How I could do that in these databases?

Comment: In Postgres [there are no db quota](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64519/postgresql-create-database-with-size-resize)

Comment: No quota in mysql either. `:I`

Comment: Cross-posted at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122311/how-to-set-the-maximum-disk-size-of-a-database-mysql-oracle-postgresql-or-db2

Answer (score 2):

In DB2 you can also specify `MAXSIZE` of each tablespace, as well as the maximum size and number of log files. For example:

```
create db mydb on /whatever dbpath on /whatever
catalog tablespace managed by automatic storage maxsize 500 M
user tablespace  managed by automatic storage maxsize 100 G;

update db cfg for mydb using logfilsiz 4000 logprimary 10 logsecond 100;
```

There is a question of temporary tablespace(s) though. By default they are created such that you cannot specify their maximum size, and really you should not. However, there is a workaround, although with a possible performance penalty.

[Link to the manual.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

In regards to PostgreSQL: As far as I know, you can't. *However*, there are workarounds explained in this posting:
https://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/421532-database-size-limiting

Hope this helps.